# Need help ID a numpy algorithm to separate an array based on common variable

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, numpy

I was hoping someone could shed some light on a problem I have. I have a single array of variables:

```
[3,4,7,8,12,18,20,25,30,31,38,43,46,51,58,59]
```

And I would like to figure out how to split them up by a common multiple/denominator/whatever you would call it...say the common variable is 13 for this array, and I want the results to be `n` number of variables, for example:

```
[4,30,43,56]
[7,20,46,59]
[12,25,38,51]
```

Is there an algorithm that can do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your query. Replace array and number as per your requirement.

```
def run():
    given_array = [3,4,7,8,12,18,20,25,30,31,38,43,46,51,58,59]
    number = 13

    final_result = []

    for e in given_array:
        d = e
        intermediate_array = []
        for f in given_array:
            if e not in intermediate_array:
                intermediate_array.append(e)
            d = d+number
            if d in given_array:
                intermediate_array.append(d)
                given_array.remove(d)
        if intermediate_array and len(intermediate_array) > 1:
            final_result.append(intermediate_array)
    print final_result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest to how i understand your question is that the numbers should be grouped by the remainder of division by n. (i%n).

```
input=[3,4,7,8,12,18,20,25,30,31,38,43,46,51,58,59]
n=13

result_dict = dict(zip(range(n),[[]]*n))
for i in input:
    result_dict[i%n] = result_dict[i%n] + [i]

{0: [],
 1: [],
 2: [],
 3: [3],
 4: [4, 30, 43],
 5: [18, 31],
 6: [58],
 7: [7, 20, 46, 59],
 8: [8],
 9: [],
 10: [],
 11: [],
 12: [12, 25, 38, 51]}
```